# Response code 404 while connecting Android client to python server

Tags: android, python, apache, http, httpurlconnection

My application uses standard httpUrlConnection code to connect to a python code on apache http server.
All permissions of network access and internet are given. Previously I could not run this code as I was not using Asych (a different thread for network access) as I am working on Android 3.0 - Latest version. Now I am finished with this part.

No when I call the code below the response code is 200 which is all good:

```
#!/Python27/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"
print "Hello."
print "</body></html>"
```

But when I use this code:

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'     
PORT = 80              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

it gives 404 response code saying Exception FileNotFoundException.

More addition, yes the code above is for a server and this is a sample code from python socket library (so all the comments are not mine). I am writing a similar server that would give database connectivity and post/get features. 
So, Just need to make sure what is the problem with the server code above?

Any hints are more than welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what the comments mean in your server program. For one `80` is not a non-privileged port (those are ones above 1024); and the code is for creating a _server_, I think what you want is to write a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above echo server code could not be connected as this was not a http server and so no response code was programmed and other information required from a http server are not implemented.

The code above it worked as it was ran from Apache so obviously that worked..
Thanks for commenting...